# How to ignore spaces before footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes

Footnote citations in biblatex ignore spacing before the citation command; how can I have the same behavior for all footnotes in a document?

Here's a MWE demonstrating the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Spacing is fine before citations     \autocite{kant:kpv} 
but not before footnotes    \footnote{A footnote \autocite{kant:ku}}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Comment: `\let\oldfootnote\footnote\def\footnote{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\oldfootnote` probably works

Comment: @DavidCarlisle An answer, please

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\def\footnote{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\oldfootnote}
```

probably works.

`\unskip` is a tex primitive to remove the previous skip (space) and here it's guarded by an `\ifhmode` test to check that you only do this if you are in horizontal mode within a paragraph not (for some reason) at the start of a paragraph when `\unskip` would (depending on the context) give an error or remove the *vertical* space before the paragraph.