# Semantic linefeeds and problem with space before footnote mark

Tags: footnotes, revision-control

I have started to use semantic linefeeds for the purposes of version control, as suggested by e.g. [Brandon Rhodes](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/one-sentence-per-line/), which I found through the answer: [How to format source to take advantage of VCS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62446/how-to-format-source-to-take-advantage-of-vcs/64538#64538)

It seems quite reasonable to put footnotes on their own line, but this inserts an ugly space before the footnote mark. Can this be dealt with in any easy fashion?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is how footnotes should work.\footnote{My mark is stuck where it should be!}

Attempting semantic linefeeds,
the footnotes seem to float away. 
\footnote{Can anyone make my mark stick to the previous character?}

\end{document}
```

This seems to ask something similar, but has not been answered: [How to ignore spaces before footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308169/how-to-ignore-spaces-before-footnotes)

Comment: `\usepackage{xpatch}` and `\xpretocmd{\footnote}{\unskip}{}{}`

Comment: @egreg That works perfectly!

Comment: Can you add that as an answer, @egreg? Or are you hoping someone ”golfs” it even further? ;)

Comment: add `%` at the end  of the sentence before the the footnote

Comment: @trmdttr I asked for an answer to the previous question; now this can be closed as duplicate.